# perl config file

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a settings file/configuration file. This would contain a list of key value pairs. There are 10 scripts that would be using this configuration file,either taking the input from it or sending output to it(key-values) or both.

I can do this by simply reading from and writing to the file..but I was thinking about a global hash in my settings file which could be accessed by all 10 scripts and which could retain the changes made by each script.
Right now,if I use :
require "setting.pl"
I am able to change the hash in my current script,but in the next script the changes are not visible..

Is there a way to do this?Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [Config file handling in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960223/config-file-handling-in-perl)

Comment: [How do you manage configuration files in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746972/how-do-you-manage-configuration-files-in-perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a [config file tied to a hash](http://p3rl.org/Config%3a%3aSimple#TIE-INTERFACE)?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this module, [AppConfig](http://p3rl.org/AppConfig).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some kind of database. You can either use mysql/sqlite/etc or create a distinct script which keeps your hash and provides read/write access to it with sockets.

Comment: A database isn't strictly needed, plain config files with simple [locking](http://p3rl.org/flock) also meet the requirement. This isn't difficult, just annoying if a programmer is used to having this automatically handled by a DBMS.